# SlickGrid: How retrieve data by pagewise

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I am working on slickgrid. i want to get rows data by pagewise Like

getPageData(3); //get third page rows data

Anyone have any idea how to do it?

Comment: if you use SlickGrid DataView, I think you can use [getFilteredItems](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/blob/master/slick.dataview.js#L1182) but you'll have to be on the page you want the data from, basically I don't think you can get the data of a page that you are not currently on, so you'll have to go to that page first then call the method... I'm saying this without trying anything though, so I'll let you try it out

Comment: Note the current master is at: github.com/6pac/SlickGrid (the MLiebman branch is dead). Check out the Ajax-loading examples.